# Installed, purged, then re-installed logwatch, now getting missing /var/cache/logwatch error

Tags: ubuntu, logwatch

On Ubuntu 12.04, I installed logwatch via

```
sudo apt-get install logwatch
```

Worked great. I made some changes to the shared conf, then realized it was better to leave those alone and override then via /etc/logwatch/conf. So I purged and reinstalled, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get purge logwatch
sudo apt-get install logwatch
```

Now, when I run logwatch, I get this error:

```
/var/cache/logwatch No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/logwatch line 633.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Create /var/cache/logwatch and ensure it's writable by the user logwatch is running as.

Comment: @EEAA - thanks, should it just be an empty file, e.g. created by touch?

Comment: It's a directory, not a file.

Comment: @EEAA - never mind, I need to create /var/cache/logwatch as a directory, thanks again